# What is the advantage of defining shell completion in .profile instead of .bashrc?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

As I understand it, under Bash, `/etc/profile`, `~/.profile`, and `~/.bash_profile` are for settings that persist across subprocesses and subshells (mostly environment variables), while `/etc/bashrc` and `~/.bashrc` are for settings that don't.  As I'm quite certain that Bash completion settings are not inherited, I would expect them to always be located in the latter set of files, but I've found a couple of instances where presumably more knowledgeable people have placed them or encouraged placing them in "profile" files instead:

- On Ubuntu (as of 20.04), installing the `bash-completion` package adds a file to `/etc/profile.d/` (sourced by `/etc/profile`) that sources the main Bash completion script.
- [Homebrew](https://brew.sh)'s [`bash-completion` formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/2037515584f1d78e37bbab526fa21b79262673a2/Formula/bash-completion.rb#L53-L58) advises the user:

  ```
  Add the following line to your ~/.bash_profile:
    [[ -r "/usr/local/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh" ]] && . "/usr/local/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh"
  ```

My best guess as to why these packages use profile files is to compensate for users who don't source their `~/.bashrc` in their profile, but that makes less sense when you consider that (on Ubuntu, at least) the default `~/.profile` sources `~/.bashrc`, and the default `~/.bashrc` already contains a section for sourcing the main Bash completion script if it exists (which I think means that the script ends up sourced twice in login shells by default?).  Moreover, on most Linux desktops, profile files are sourced on login, followed by the user's GUI desktop starting up, and then any terminal emulators within that GUI start non-login shells, so if you use a terminal emulator on a Linux desktop, chances are the profile files aren't getting sourced in that shell.

Why would these packages have the completion scripts sourced as part of the profile files instead of the bashrc files?  What's the advantage of doing it that way?

Comment: I can't give you a good answer, but I have the exact same question right know! I personally decided to move the Homebrew completion stuff to my `~/.bashrc`. I agree that it makes no sense to source completion stuff in `~/.profile` only.